# is it possible to login to Yahoo and reach to certain message?

Tags: php, email, curl, authentication, yahoo

Is it possible to login to Yahoo and getting a certain message ?

I'm going to struggle with this if you say it's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By messages, are you referring to Yahoo! Mail? If so you can use their web service to do so:

http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work. You can do it with cURL in php. To login these tutorial should help: [Video Tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/use-curl-login-websites-script) and [code example](http://ryan.ifupdown.com/2009/06/30/login-with-curl-and-php/).

Hope that helps :)